# A way of debugging GLU with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, opengl, glu

I'm using GLUTess to tesselate polygons. Sometimes it crashes with a null pointer issue and I have no way of knowing why since I just link to glu32.lib . Is there a way to see the source and get the exact line it crashes on?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do certain things never crash whith debugger on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384066/why-do-certain-things-never-crash-whith-debugger-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to see the source and get the exact line it crashes on?

1. You can build program on linux. If issue persists, AND if corresponding *.so contains debugging info (and if you have source code in your distribution), then you'll be able to find line number. Do not expect source of glu to be easy to understand, though.
2. Or you could grab [mesa3d](http://www.mesa3d.org/) source code and build it with debug info, then use mesa3d's glu32.dll (drop into application's directory). If issue persists, you may be able to catch it. Keep in mind that mesa3d is not certified, so it isn't guaranteed to be totally conforming to OpenGL standard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the source and debugging symbols (.pdb file) for glu32.lib. You can get them in two possible ways:
1. From the vendor
2. By compiling glu32.lib yourself